# Table in unity is not saving values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The table keeps resetting after pressing another button. I want it to keep the values after pressing another button so I can show them in the UI.

The hierarchy in unity goes like this:

Panel (Object that group all the buttons)
Ciasto, Mieso, Sos, Rozmiar (Categories of the buttons)
Grube, Cienkie, Kurczak, Miesiane, Wolowina, Ostry, Mieszane, Lagodny,  maly, duzy, sredni (The actual buttons each of them in a category)

And in buttons I have a text and object named `Funkcja` which holds the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class KebabMakerPanel : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI zamowienie;

    public string[] kebab = { "ciasto", "mięso", "sos", "rozmiar" };

    #region ciasto
    public void cienkie()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[0] = "cienkie";
        }

    }

    public void grube()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[0] = "grube";
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region mieso
    public void miesoMieszane()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[1] = "grube";
        }

    }

    public void miesoKurczak()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[1] = "grube";
        }

    }

    public void miesoWolowina()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[1] = "grube";
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region sos
    public void sosMieszany()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[2] = "mieszany";
        }

    }

    public void sosOstry()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[2] = "ostry";
        }

    }

    public void sosLagodny()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[2] = "lagodny";
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region rozmiar

    public void rozmiarMaly()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[3] = "maly";
        }

    }

    public void rozmiarSredni()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[3] = "sredni";
        }

    }

    public void rozmiarDuzy()
    {
        if (kebab.Length > 0)
        {
            kebab[3] = "duzy";
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region zamowienie
    public void WyswietlKebabUI()
    {
        string tekst = "Kebab:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < kebab.Length; i++)
        {
            tekst += kebab[i] + "\n";
        }

        zamowienie.text = tekst;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I want the table named kebab to save the values when the corresponding button is pressed so I can show them in the UI

Comment: You forgot to include button code. "The table keeps resetting" - what is *table*? Is field `kebab` your table? I'd expect to see recipes and ingredients (with counter) and a smart way to add/replace ingredient, with lookups, rather that funny way of changing array items at fixed index. Also note your checks are not guarding from  invalid index exceptions properly.

Comment: Yes kebab is the table, and this is the button code. Each of the functions is attached to a single button

Comment: Is one script referenced for all the buttons? (meaning all the buttons reference one game object where this script is attached) or do you have each button with its own copy of this script? How is the relationship between them? It is a bit difficult to know the cause without seeing the interactions. Post some pictures of the components of each GO in the Inspector and tell us how where the `kebab` list is displayed so that you know it is right or wrong.